# What does repair and optimize tables in PHP MyAdmin actually do?

Tags: phpmyadmin

Sometimes I repair or optimize (normally both) my tables in PHP MyAdmin  Often it fixes a problem I'm having.  My question is what am I actually doing when I undertake these actions?

Is there any danger?  Is any data changed or moved?

Comment: I don't mind being marked down but coudl you at least leave a reason so I know how to improve please

Answer (score -1):

## Someone told me Optimize is...

Do you remember when we used to defrag HDDs? Table optimization is something similar to that. It restructures a table so that data pages are next to each other and releases unused pages. If you ever delete a large part of the table data, optimization shrinks the table file down to the proper size.

Comment: If this answer is incorrect could you provide a correct answer and also mark me down please